# Releasing OpenSSL resources: SSL_CTX_free

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, openssl

I'm loading certificates from memory, adding it to the certificate store, and then performing validation:

```
char base64EncodedCert[] = "...";
const int autoDetermineLength = -1;
BIO* memoryCert = BIO_new_mem_buff(base64EncodedCert, autoDetermineLength);
X509* certificate = PEM_read_bio_X509(memoryCert, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
BIO_free(sslCompatibleMemoryCert);
X509_STORE_add_cert(certificateStore, certificate);
```

Based on the code:

1. The buffer `base64EncodedCert` only needs to be in memory for as long as the `BIO` is needed, as described in the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html).
2. Once the certificate is created, the `BIO` is no longer created and can be freed. This is an observation; looking at the *X509* structure, this seems reasonable.
3. I suspect that the ownership of the `X509` object is passed on the the certificate store via `X509_STORE_add_cert`. That is, I don't need to keep track of the newly created certificate, it is automatically tied to the lifetime of the certificate store.
4. The certificate store comes from the SSL context, and so its lifetime is tied to the SSL context (`SSL_CTX`).
5. It's therefore my conclusion that when I call `SSL_CTX_free` the certificates I've added to the certificate store are released accordingly.

Am I correct? Are there any other memory considerations?
Thank you for your time and contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers:

1. Yes, you are correct
2. Yes, you are correct
3. Yes - as long as `X509_STORE_add_cert` **succeded**. In other words: if `X509_STORE_add_cert` returned value **greater than zero** - ownership of the `X509` object **is** passed on the the certificate store; if `X509_STORE_add_cert` returned **zero** - ownership of the `X509` object **is not** passed on the the certificate store - you need to handle that.
4. Yes - if the certificate store comes from the SSL context
5. Yes, you are correct

I hope that helps.

Comment: Your reply certainly does help! Would you happen to have any references?

Comment: Yes - my reference is the OpenSSL's source code - I looked at it to answer your question.